# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars Popping despite np.vectorize

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

While I was plotting logarithms on a graph using Matplotlib `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` popped up. I searched Stack for this and there was an answer which suggested using `numpy.vectorize()` but when I tried it, it didn't work and outputted the exact same error. The code is given below.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100, num = 10)
plt.plot(x, x, label = "x")
plt.plot(x, np.vectorize(math.log2(64*x - 160)), label = "Log2(64x - 160)")
```

Why is isn't `numpy.vectorize()` working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with `vectorize`. The problem is that you can't do log2 of negative numbers. If you change the starting range as follows, it works:

```py
x = np.linspace(3, 100, num = 10)
plt.plot(x, x, label = "x")
plt.plot(x, np.log2(64*x - 160), label = "Log2(64x - 160)")
```